# pushing an element onto the stack ocaml

Tags: stack, ocaml

Can some explain to me how i would push an element on to a stack in ocaml as well as check to see if it is an integer? I assume you would check to see if it was in a variable digit = "0123456789. Mostly im unsure sure about what variable you should use in the function, i know you would pass in a stack variable but what would the "integer" variable would be?

```
let PushI (*what var goes here an int? or digit?*) (stk : stackVal list) : stackVal list  = 

let meth_Pop (stk : stackVal list) : stackVal list = 
(*just pops a value from the top of the stack if nothing in stack will return an error*)
    match stk with
    | h::t -> t
    | _ -> ERROR::stk
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to answer this question without seeing the definition of the type `stackVal`.

Let's assume it looks like this:

```
type stackVal = Int of int | Float of float
```

Then I would personally define pushI to take an `int` parameter.

You might be working in some context where you're getting tokens from a stream of characters. In that case you might want to define all your push functions to take strings rather than actual numeric values.

If you tell us (StackOverflow answerers) more about your problem we might be able to help a little more.

For the first part of your question, you can look at the `meth_Pop` function. It shows that a stack is a list, and the the top of the stack is the head of the list (`h` in the function) and the rest of the stack is the tail of the list (`t` in the function).

To push an int value onto a stack using the above `stackVal`, you would have something like this:

```
let push myInt myStack = Int myInt :: myStack
```